# Convergence, series with exp and ln

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\exp(n)}{\exp(n\sqrt[n]{n})\ln^{2}n}$$

Tell, if the series converges.

Please verify my answer.

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{\exp(n)}{\exp(n\sqrt[n]{n})\ln^{2}n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{\exp(n)}{\exp(n)\frac{1}{n}\exp(n)\ln^{2}n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{n}{\exp(n)\ln^{2}n}$$

Comparison test

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+1}{\exp(n+1)\ln^{2}(n+1)}\frac{\exp(n)\ln^{2}n}{n}=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{e}\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{\ln^{2}n}{\ln^{2}(n+1)}=\frac{1}{e}$$

The series converges.

Comment: You seem to have put $$e^{n\sqrt[n]n}=e^n\frac{1}{n}e^n$$ This doesn't look right. Perhaps you meant $$e^{n\sqrt[n]n}=e^{n^{n+1/n}}\;\;?$$

Comment: That's not true: $exp(n\sqrt[n]{n}) = exp(n) * exp(\sqrt[n]{n})$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry @Joggi, but I'm afraid you'll have to review your notes in exponents theory. It **must** be $$a^{x+y}=a^x\cdot a^y\;\;,\;\;a^{xy}=(a^x)^y\Longrightarrow e^{n\sqrt[n]n}=(e^n)^{\sqrt[n]n}=(e^{\sqrt[n]n})^n\neq e^n\cdot e^{\sqrt[n]n}$$

Comment: OK, sorry... :-) I missed it. So I'm going back to this task. Thanks!

Comment: No! I think, @Joggi, you're confusing big time the exponential function with the *logarithmic function*. With the last one we certainly have $$\log\sqrt[n]n=\frac{1}{n}\log n$$but not with its inverse function...

Comment: at least $$ln^2(n) = 2 ln(n) $$?

Comment: No, @Joggi: $\,\log n^2=2\log n\neq \log^2n=(\log n)^2\,$ I honestly think you should read the basic of exponential and logarithmic functions before engaging in calculus any further. When dealing with series, one usually expect student to already know all thi stuff from high school! So you forgot, no big deal...but then try to fix this ASAP.

Comment: OK. Thanks one more!